# Reading and Writing a class data to binary file in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
class Student 
{
public:
Student *prev;  
char S_Name[15];
char F_Name[15];
int Reg_Num;
char Section;
char MAoI[15];
float CGPA;
Student *next;
}
```

I have the above class and I want to write the data to a binary file of the link list when I exit the program  and again read it back and form a link list when the program is run.
I have tried but failed on several attempts !

The code for Entering data `Student * Add_Entry()
{
    Student *temp=new Student();

```
char s_Name[15];
char f_Name[15];
int reg_Num;
char section;
char mAoI[15];
float cGPA;

cout <<"**********************Menu***************************\n ";
cout<<"\nEnter the Studets name \"";
cin>>s_Name;

cout<<"\nEnter Father`s name \"";
cin>>f_Name;

cout<<"\nEnter the Registration Number \"";
cin>>reg_Num;

cout<<"\nEnter the Section \"";
cin>>section;

cout<<"\nEnter the Major Area of Interest \"";
cin>>mAoI;

cout<<"\nEnter the Current CGPA \"";
cin>>cGPA;

strcpy_s(temp->S_Name,s_Name);
strcpy_s(temp->F_Name,f_Name);
temp->Reg_Num=reg_Num;
temp->Section=section;
strcpy_s(temp->MAoI,mAoI);
temp->CGPA=cGPA;
temp->next=NULL;
temp->prev=NULL;
return temp;

//temp=Create_node(s_Name,f_Name,reg_Num,section,mAoI,cGPA);
```

}`

To read from file i use `    char *buffer;

```
    ifstream reader;
    reader.open("student.bin",ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(reader.is_open)
    {
        do
        {
            reader.read(buffer,ch);
            if(Header==NULL)
            {
                Header=(Student)*buffer;
                temporary=Header;
            }

            else
            {
                temporary->next=(Student)*buffer;
                temporary=temporary->next;
            }
        }while(buffer!=NULL);
    }
```

`

And to write I use `                    temporary=Header;
                    //Backup Entries
                    ofstream writer;
                    writer.open("student.bin",ios::out | ios::binary);

```
                while(temporary!=NULL)
                {   
                    writer.write((char)* temporary,sizeof(temporary));
                    temporary=temporary->next;
                }

                writer.close();
```

`

Comment: Can you post the code from your most recent attempt please?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you create your linked list and how you write it to file please?

Comment: As before, please edit your question to include this information.  Can you also explain exactly how the code "fails" please?  If it crashes, try to determine which line that happens on.  If the code runs but gives surprising output, explain what output you see and what you expected.

Comment: On load, you don't appear to be filling in the "next" pointer for the final entry in the list, nor filling in any of the "prev" pointers. (and who knows what's happening in the code you haven't posted)

Comment: It is giving error related to data type conversion

Comment: I changed according to what you said, now the  error is 
**Students_info.cpp(433): error C3867: 'std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::is_open': function call missing argument list; use '&std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::is_open' to create a pointer to member
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>**

Comment: is_open is a function call, and needs ()s. i.e. `is_open()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Header=(Student)*buffer;
```

Means: Take buffer, which is probably a pointer to char, and dereference it, to get a `char`. Then cast that `char` into a `Student`. The compiler has no idea how to convert a `char` into a `Student`.

If instead you do this:

```
Header= *((Student *)buffer);
```

It will cast the pointer to a pointer of the right type, and then dereference it to give a struct, which can be copied.

You do that all over the place.

Also, when reading, you don't fill in the "next" pointer for the final item, nor the "prev" pointer for any. Although the "next" pointer in the last saved item might be zero (assuming it was saved correctly), the prev pointers could point at anything. Best practice would be to initialise everything correctly.

Also:

```
if(reader.is_open)
```

should be:

```
if(reader.is_open())
```

Comment: Will I have to write individual entries to the file and read them back ?

Comment: You should be able to do more or less what you're doing now, but you need to fix the bugs as described (and maybe more). I notice you've accepted my answer - if you have additional questions, you should open a new question. If I didn't actually answer your question, you should update your question with more information.

Comment: I have fixed the bugs but still the problem exists